# FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, dataset

I've been working with Football Transfers dataset and I'm trying to print the rows with specific column values. As you can see from Line 11 and Line 12 of the code, I've successfully printed the rows where the Transfer Fee is 222000000 and other values. But I can't seem to print the rows whose market value isn't 'NaN'

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

data0 = 'C:/Users/Siddhardh/Desktop/OiDS Project/Code/Transfers.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(data0)
#print(data.head())

#data1 = data.loc[data['Transfer_fee'] == 222000000]
#print(data1.head())

if(data['Market_value'] != 'NaN'):
    print(data.head())
```

This is the error I'm getting;

```
C:\Users\Siddhardh\Desktop\OiDS Project\Code\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py:1115: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Siddhardh/Desktop/Python/Projects/OiDS_Transfers/Central_Code.py", line 14, in <module>
    if(data['Market_value'] != 'NaN'):
  File "C:\Users\Siddhardh\Desktop\OiDS Project\Code\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that:

- the result is computed for each row **separately** (so that the
  result is a boolean **Series**),
- but you actually need a boolean **scalar** (either a **single** *True*
  or a **single** *False*).

To convert such a boolean *Series* to a single value, use either *any()*
or *all()*, according to what is needed.

Another detail: *Market_value*, as I suppose, is a *float* column and
*NaN* is only the way the *not-a-number* value is printed.
Actually, it is a special value of **float** type.
So comparing with *'NaN'* as a string is wrong.

Note also that *NaN* is not equal to any other value, including other *NaN*.
To check whether any value is / is not *NaN*, use *isna()* or *notna()*
functions.

So, to sum up, run instead:

```
if(data['Market_value'].notna().all()):
    print(data.head())
```